# Where source code is the Qt SDK installer for linux?

Tags: linux, qt, installation

If you have experience with QtSDK in Linux, You must see an GUI installer in Linux. I like to create an installer like this, but I can't find the code of installer to read code and create an installer like it.

Anyone knows about this kind of GUI installer on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be helpful  http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/

Especially for Qt Developers http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/qt-developers.html

Comment: Are you sure the installer of QtSDK in Linux is built with Bitrock? Or just you want to get me a hint?